Using parameter in ReMap for reclassify tool in ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to reclassify a raster in ArcGIS Pro that will reclassify a text type field into a number that is entered in the tool. The number will be between -1 and -0.009. I also want areas that have no data to be reclassified to 0. The cell size and snap raster parameters will be set by the user in the parameters area of the interface. I need the new reclassified raster to be binary with only 0 and the inputted number being the only two values.
My problem is that I am receiving this error:
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Reclassify). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter remap.
I take this to mean that I cannot use a defined variable within the remap? Some guidance would be great. The number needs to be able to be adjusted as it is related to elevation and areas with low elevation will need a smaller number.
Here is my script.
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import*
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Vector_layers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
DEM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
RasterSubtractionValue= arcpy.GetParameter (2)


##Merges the input vector layers into a single layer.
Stormwater_Merged= arcpy.management.Merge(Vector_layers, "Stormwater_Merged")

##Adds a field calls Reclass
arcpy.management.AddField(Stormwater_Merged, "Reclass", "DOUBLE")

##Calculates the field to be equal to the number inputed into the tool
arcpy.management.CalculateField(Stormwater_Merged, "Reclass", RasterSubtractionValue)

##Converts the merged vector layer into a raster using the Reclass field as the classifying field.
Stormwater_Raster=arcpy.conversion.FeatureToRaster(Stormwater_Merged, "sdsFeatureName", "Stormwater_Raster")

# Extract unique text values from the raster's attribute table
unique_values = set()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Stormwater_Raster, ["SDSFEATURENAME"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        unique_values.add(row[0])
        
#Prepare the list of remap values using the unique raster values and mapping
remap_list = []

# Now that we have unique values, add them to remap_list with placeholder numeric values
# Assign default values like 0 for now, or handle them as needed later
for value in unique_values:
    remap_list.append([value, RasterSubtractionValue])  # Replace '0' with any default numeric value if needed

myRemapValue= RemapValue(remap_list)

# Reclassify the raster using myRemapValue and set NODATA areas to 0
reclassified_raster = Reclassify(Stormwater_Raster, "Value", myRemapValue, "NODATA")

# Set areas without data to 0
reclassified_raster_zeroed = Con(IsNull(reclassified_raster), 0, reclassified_raster)

# Save the final reclassified raster
reclassified_raster_zeroed.save("StormwaterRaster_Reclassified")

Alternatively I have tried to calculate a new field in the merged vector layer with the number that is inputted by the user. Then trying to use that in the reclassify tool so that there would only need to be one value that was reclassified. This worked when the number was -1 but created a gradient when the number had a decimal. Hopefully that makes sense. This is my first time posting so apologies if there is more detail that is helpful.
